# Edit Single Row And Refresh Just That Row In Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 10000 rows in my datagridview,now when i edit one of the rows,i should refresh all the rows with select stored procedure that i wrote.

How do you suggest to me to refresh(select) just that edited row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already added the new values, it might not be needed to refresh your whole grid, only refresh it when you need another record, or update that row and get the index and reload only that row using the index that you already have

Comment: thanks,i thought if after edit i do select(just for that row)my datagridview will show just that row,you say its not correct?

Comment: You can update that row only with the new values after the update, the grid wont show only that row